# Combining two adjacent collections to create Json rows

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, dynamic

I have a `List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>` which after serialization using NewtonSoft gives something like this:

```
[{
    "Header1" : [
        "25%",
        "1.4%",
        "0.93%"
    ],
    "Header2" : [
        "51%",
        "42%",
        "16"
    ],
    "Header3" : [
        "8%",
        "99%",
        "11.37%"
    ]
}]
```

I need to transform this into a table of data with key-value pairs, something like this JSON:

```
{
    "data":
    [{
        "Header1" : "25%",
        "Header2" : "51%",
        "Header3" : "8%",
    },
    {
        "Header1" : "1.4%",
        "Header2" : "42%",
        "Header3" : "99%",
    }]
}
```

Can you please suggest an elegant way of achieving this without doing a manual `foreach` loop?

Kindly note the value of the Headers are not static; I get them at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this using Linq methods:

```
var initialData = new List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        { "Header1", new List<string> {"25%", "1.4%", "0.93%" } },
        { "Header2", new List<string> {"51%", "42%", "16%" } },
        { "Header3", new List<string> {"8%", "99%", "11.37%" } }
    },
};

var result = new
{
    data = initialData.First()
            .Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Select((v, i) => 
                           new { Key = kvp.Key, Value = v, Index = i }))
            .SelectMany(a => a)
            .GroupBy(a => a.Index)
            .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value))
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The above code will give this output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Header1": "25%",
      "Header2": "51%",
      "Header3": "8%"
    },
    {
      "Header1": "1.4%",
      "Header2": "42%",
      "Header3": "99%"
    },
    {
      "Header1": "0.93%",
      "Header2": "16%",
      "Header3": "11.37%"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Apologies for late response.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem.  If this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark icon to the left of the answer.